# Printing a List of byte array from a webservice in a single job

Tags: java, web-services, printing, arrays, thermal-printer

I'm trying to print to a thermal usb printer connected to a machine running windows, a list of commands received one by one from one webservice. The problem is that I need to create a single PrintJob with all data received, and not a job for every byte[] received. Here is my code:

```
...//communicated with webserver and received data using "message" variable

PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrintService.getName());

if (defaultPrintService != null) {
    sendMessage("connected"); //send message to the server to start receiving data to print
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

        while (!message.contentEquals("done")) {
                try {
                    message = (String) in.readObject();

                    if (!message.contentEquals("done")) {
                        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(message.getBytes(), flavor, null);
                        DocPrintJob job = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
                        job.print(doc, null);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {        
                    // Handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

What happens there is that windows create one printjob for each message received (ok, I knew that since the beginning) and this take minutes to print some lines.

The other problem is, if I print direct to the printer through network, it prints fine. Through USB, it just print some commands like line feed and paper cut, not the text (like it does via network).

What am I missing?

Thank you people!

**UPDATE**

I've concatenated all received strings into a single one, and them tried to print the getBytes() from that String. Now the printer prints fine, but again, some commands where not executed and the layout got messy and looks like charset got wrong, because accented chars are also not working